# equivalence of Euclidean and manhattan metric

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

take a sequence of points $x_n$ in $R^m$, we want to show that $x_n \rightarrow x$ under $\rho_e(x_n,x) = (\sum_{i=1}^{m} (x_n^i - x^i)^2)^{1/2}$ iff $x_n \rightarrow x$ under $\rho_m(x_n , x) = \sum_{i=1}^{m}|x_n^i - x^i|$.

We recall that $x_n \rightarrow x$ under $\rho$ iff $\forall \epsilon > 0 , \exists N \in naturals \space s.t. \forall n\geq N , \rho(x_n ,x) $

So far I managed to show (I think) that manhattan implies euclidean :
$\epsilon \geq \sum_{i=1}^{m}|x_n^i - x^i| \geq (\sum_{i=1}^{m} (x_n^i - x^i)^2)^{1/2}$ given $(\sum_{i=1}^{m}|x_n^i - x^i|)^2 \geq \sum_{i=1}^{m} (x_n^i - x^i)^2$

However I am quite stuck for the other direction, how do I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that for any $j$ you have $|x_n^j - x^j| \leq \left( \sum_{i=1}^{m} (x_n^i - x^i)^2 \right)^{1/2} $ since all the terms on the RHS are positive.

Consequently, $\rho_m (x_n , x) = \sum_{i=1}^{m}|x_n^i - x^i| \leq m \cdot \left( \sum_{i=1}^{m} (x_n^i - x^i)^2 \right)^{1/2} = m \cdot \rho_e (x_n, x)$.

You should be fine from here.

Comment: This is perfect! I understand how we go on from here, thank you